# Procedure for determining the levels of Acrylamide from a cup of coffee

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, food-chemistry, extraction

For experimental purposes, I want to determine the level of Acrylamide in cups of coffee. Is there a method that doesn't use spectrometric analysis to determine it as I do not have access to it in the lab. Is Acrylamide a Heterocyclic Amine?

Comment: Acrylamide is a $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated amide (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylamide). Also, your question is not clear. You want to analyze acrylamide in coffee or acrylamide in a plastic coffee-cup?

Comment: I want to analyse it in coffee...

Comment: [Analysis of Acrylamide in Coffee](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-409517-5.00111-X)